# Issue with MySql upgrade from 5.1 to 5.6 for Jboss SOA - p v 4.3

Tags: mysql

We are using JBoss SOA P v- 4.3, we have recently upgraded Mysql version to 5.6 from 5.1 and are facing some issue with the jboss start up.

We are using MySQL instead of Hypersonic database for Jboss in-memory database which jboss used internally, MySQL is recommended for production use.

This Database is used by JBoss Enterprise SOA Platform to persist registry services and the message store.

Therein we have a table named “AuthToken” having a column “CREATED”, details below.

```
Column Name : CREATED
Type : timestamp
Default : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

We are getting the below error at jboss startup :

```
07:57:42,561 INFO [JDBCDataStore] Generated token 'authToken:F0D1A900-88E4-11E3-B34B-8ED0EAFF8EE4' for user: 'jbossesb/JBoss ESB User'
07:57:42,712 ERROR [AuthTokenTable] Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATED' at row 1
07:57:42,781 ERROR [GetAuthTokenFunction] com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATED' at row 1
07:57:42,781 ERROR [RequestHandler] com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATED' at row 1
```

Kindly suggest if this error can be resolved by some jboss configuration change or we should be looking on database side for it’s resolution.

This works fine when we are using MySQL 5.1.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation%3A+Data+truncation%3A+Incorrect+datetime+value%3A+''+for+column+'CREATED'+at+row+1